# Ending tag in XML child

Tags: c++, xml, qt, parsing

I am having tough time writing a XML file. Everything is written perfectly, but the ending tag is missing.

Expected XML FILE:

```
<HEADER>
  <CHILD Name="" Value = ""></CHILD>
  <CHILD Name="" Value = ""><SUBSCHILD Name=""></SUBCHILD></CHILD>
  <CHILD Name="" Value = ""></CHILD>
  <CHILD Name="" Value = ""><SUBSCHILD Name=""></SUBCHILD></CHILD>
</HEADER>
```

Actual XML FILE:

```
    <HEADER>
      <CHILD Name="" Value = "">
      <CHILD1 Name="" Value = ""><SUBSCHILD1 Name="">
      <CHILD Name="" Value = "">
      <CHILD1 Name="" Value = ""><SUBSCHILD1 Name="">
    </HEADER>
```

Writing XML file:

```
QXmlGet xmlget;
xmlget.load(file.xml);
xmlget.findAndDescend("HEADER");
QxmlPut xmlput(xmlget);
for(int i=0; i<child.count(); i++)
{
    xmlput.putString("CHILD", "")
    xmlput.setAttributeString("Name", child.at(i).name);
    xmlput.setAttributeString("Value", child.at(i).value);
    if(child.at(i).Subchild.size() != 0)
    {
        xmlput.putString("SUBCHILD", "");
        xmlput.setAttributeString("Name", child.at(i).subchild);
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine, except for the ending tag which spoils the whole XML file

Comment: Should `</HEADER1>` be `</HEADER>`

Comment: Sorry, corrected! @EdHeal can you check now?

Comment: @thuga can you check this?